# How do I keep my wallet connected and refresh the page without reconnecting?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

https://solana-labs.github.io/wallet-adapter/example/ How do I keep my wallet connected and refresh the page without reconnecting?

Answer (score 0):

Solana **wallet adapter** has the property autoConnect we have to set it to **true**. and Also have to set cookies on the front end if needed. here is an example.

```
      <ConnectionProvider endpoint="https://api.devnet.solana.com">
            <WalletProvider
                wallets={wallets}
                autoConnect={
                    cookies.get('_sToken') &&
                    cookies.get('_Platform') === 'solana'
                        ? true
                        : false
                }
            ></WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
```